# Passing variables to a has_one relationship in PhpActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, orm, phpactiverecord

I'm using phpactiverecord (http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) in a project.

I have the below relationship definded. Is there anyway to pass a variable to it so I can change `language_id` on the fly?

```
static $has_one = array(
  array(
    'language', 
    'class_name' => 'Pages_lang', 
    'conditions' => array('language_id=1')
  )
);
```

I looked on the docs and it appears you can do:

```
static $has_one = array(
  array('language', 
    'class_name' => 
    'Pages_lang', 
    'conditions' => array('language_id=?','1'))
);
```

But passing a variable in:

```
static $has_one = array(
  array('language', 
    'class_name' => 
    'Pages_lang', 
    'conditions' => array('language_id=?',$language_id))
);
```

throws an error.

Im not really sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you add some more information about what you are trying to achieve? The database connection either exists or not, and I don't see why one would want to change the connections on the fly. How does your database schema look, and what are you trying to do here? (please, edit the question with the new information, don't add the schema as a comment :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` variables only make sense in the context of objects. They come into existance before an object of that type is actually created (instantiated).

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve here, but you most probably want to change the variable at some point in your program's control flow. In order to do that, you must either create and call a method within the class that sets the value of that static variable (advisable, see example code below) or set it explicitly from your main code (not advisable, also requires your variable to be `public`)

```
class Foo
{
    static $has_one = 'initial value';

    public static function setHasOne($value) {
        self::$has_one=$value;
    }
}

// main code:
Foo::setHasOne('new value');
```

For the sake of simplicity I've used a string variable here, but it works just the same with arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are pointing at for this advice, but the `$has_one` is an object you use that is defined in the model-object by `phpactiverecord`. I don't see any merrit in that setHasONe function, as it is supposed to correlate with your database!

Comment: The answer I gave here was just trying to show the concept of static variables in PHP. I do not know what $has_one does in phpactiverecord, and do not know if setting that variable in your own code makes any sense or not. (That's also why I called the class `Foo`)